# HTTP requests not working when using Gunicorn geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker but socketio web sockets are

Tags: gunicorn, nginx-reverse-proxy, gevent, flask-socketio

I am trying to deploy my flask app on a headless pi. My flask app uses Socketio to create websockets to push sensor data to my routes. I also also use flask WTForms in my flask app. The flask app functioned as expected when running locally on my laptop.

My challenge is to deploy the flask app to my pi using Nginx and Gunicorn so that the http requests and websockets both work.

I have deployed on my pi using Nginx and Gunicorn. When I used the standard gunicorn worker class, the app forms all functioned correctly, but the websockets  were not being established. I corrected this by using the worker class geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker. This established the websocket connection and enabled the real time data to be pushed to my flask app, but now none of the forms function, I assume the http requests are being blocked.

Do I need to use multiple workers, and therefore implement a message queue?

my Gunicorn service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject Flask app
Requires=flask_app.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=pi
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/pi/myproject/env/bin"
ExecStart=/home/pi/myproject/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 1 --bind unix:/home/pi/myproject/flask_app.sock -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker --log-file /home/pi/myproject/gunicorn.log wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My Nginx  configuration is:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name localhost.local www.localhost.local;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/pi/myproject/flask_app.sock;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;

 }

   location /socket.io {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/pi/myproject/flask_app.sock;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
        proxy_buffering off;  # Disable buffering for WebSocket connections
   }
}
```

snippets from my flask app showing the socket connection:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

app = Flask(__name__)

socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='gevent')

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/display')
def handle_display_connect():
    try:    
        
        
        table_data, data,  = fetch_display_data()
        


        socketio.emit('display_data', {
            'display_table_data': table_data,
            'display_charts_data': data,
            
        }, namespace='/display')

        #start background task
        gevent_task = spawn(emit_display_data)
        gevent_task.start()
        socket_tasks_display[request.sid] = gevent_task


        

    except Exception as e:
        # Handle connection error
        print(f"Error during connection: {str(e)}")
        socketio.emit('error', {'message': 'Connection error'}, namespace='/display')


if __name__ =='__main__':
                
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Any thoughts would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please explain in detail what happens with your HTTP requests, and include relevant logs from Gunicorn and/or nginx.

Comment: When i submit a flask form, the page goes to a loading mode, eventually i get a 502 bad error gateway. 'settings_config:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Bad Gateway)'
Neither the nginx or the gunicorn log display errors, 
'[2023-09-18 13:13:52 +0100] [518] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-09-18 13:13:52 +0100] [518] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/home/pi/myproject/flask_app.sock (518)
[2023-09-18 13:13:52 +0100] [518] [INFO] Using worker: geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker

Comment: when i use only the -k gevent, the forms all work fine, but the gunicorn log

raise RuntimeError('You need to use the gevent-websocket server. '
RuntimeError: You need to use the gevent-websocket server. See the Deployment section of the documentation for more information.

Comment: I'm really not aware of any issues with forms when using gevent alone or with the gevent-websocket worker. The only part I'm really not used to see is that you are listening on a unix socket. I suggest you test a regular socket, maybe gevent and/or gevent-websocket do not fully support unix sockets.